# SWRL rule on Protegé 4.3 used to initialize variables

Tags: ontology, swrl

I'm working on understanding how to initialize a variable's value when using an ontology (written on OWL) and SWRL rules. To test this initialization problem I've created (on Protegé 4.3) a test class called `Test`, an individual of that class called `Indiv` and a property called `Prop`, with `Test` domain and `int` range. After that, I created a rule like this: `Test(Indiv)->Prop(Indiv,5)`. If I understood a previous explanation correctly, now `Indiv` should have a `5` on its `Prop` property, but I can't see anything happening (Probably that's another question, how can I see on Protegé the change the rule does?)

Comment: which reasoner are you using?

Comment: As @Ignazio is alluding, you'll need to use enable a reasoner that can process the SWRL rules in order to see inferences based on the rules.

Comment: My bad, I didn't include that I'm using the Pellet plug in for Protegé as a reasoner.